# Why are neo4j browser returning different elementId's on the same nodes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Why are neo4j browser returning different elementId's on the same nodes?

For example;

```
MATCH (a)
RETURN elementId(a)
```

returns something like;

- "4:03bd44da-415d-4ed9-a682-7510a61bc8e3:0"
- "4:03bd44da-415d-4ed9-a682-7510a61bc8e3:1"
- "4:03bd44da-415d-4ed9-a682-7510a61bc8e3:2"
- "4:03bd44da-415d-4ed9-a682-7510a61bc8e3:3"

whereas;

```
MATCH (a)
RETURN a
```

returns this;

```
{
  "identity": 0,
  "labels": [
    "SomeLabel"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "SomeProperty": "Blah",
  },
  "elementId": "0"
}
```

For example "4:03bd44da-415d-4ed9-a682-7510a61bc8e3:0" vs "0".

I would expect the same elementId string.

Comment: This is a bug, I reproduced it as well. Will post an answer when I get more updates on this internally.

Comment: Thanks @fbiville - I'm looking forward to it. Also, is matching on elementId() an O(n) operation or is it fast/indexed? The docs says nothing and no one answers on discord.

Comment: You shouldn't use elementId, in your queries as it can get reused when a node or relationship is deleted. You should use some application generated ids.

Comment: @CharchitKapoor I know and I do. That has nothing to do with my questions.